# Can I successfully sue an online match making website for matching me with a fraudster?

Tags: contract-law, marriage, divorce, online

Say I used a match making website to find a girl.
The website matched our personalities, likes, dislike, etc.

It turns out that this women is a fraud. She is drop dead beautiful, but her intention was to suck off all my assets, particularly through divorce settlements.

I will be taking legal actions on her no doubt,
but can I also successfully sue the online match making website for matching me with the fraudster?

Comment: Divorce settlements? Talk about a long game.

Comment: As a person of **sound mind**, it is **your** choice whome you in the end chose. Independent of any contract conditions of the matchmaking site, in the end it will come down to the fact that it was your choice to make. [Legal definition of **Sound mind**](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Sound+mind)

Answer (score 5):

There are only two arguments you can make:

1. The match making website did something wrong. I don't see how you can make this argument unless you have some reason to suspect they actually did something wrong.
2. Strict liability applies. I think this fails for two reasons. One is that no theory of strict liability that I know of would apply to this situation. The other is that this is precisely the kind of risk that a user of the site should be protecting themselves from because it is much easier to detect fraud when you have extensive contact with someone than when you just operate a matchmaking service.

So absent some evidence they did something wrong, such as ignoring specific warning signs from this particular user, there is no way such a suit could succeed.

Answer (score 3):

**Good Luck**

By signing up to use the website, you obviously agreed to a contract with the company behind the website, and I'm sure the company's lawyers had you agree that you would have no legal recourse against them, unless it is binding arbitration with the arbiter of their choice, which would hardly be advantageous to you. I'm sure they absolved themselves of any liability, even if they did background checks on website users and still missed things like criminal records. And the website company will be hardly responsible for personal behavior and actions of their clients after the match. Read the contract; it's legally binding and more than likely perfectly valid in your jurisdiction.